# Removing background color from image opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have many images of specimen which have uncontrollable background color.  Some of them have black background.  Some of them have white background. Some of them have green background, etc.

I would like to remove these background color of a given image where the object in the image is just only one specimen.  I try this code but it does not work as i expect.

```
def get_holes(image, thresh):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        im_bw = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        im_bw_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_bw)

        _, contour, _ = cv2.findContours(im_bw_inv, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for cnt in contour:
            cv2.drawContours(im_bw_inv, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)

        nt = cv2.bitwise_not(im_bw)
        im_bw_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(im_bw_inv, nt)
        return im_bw_inv


    def remove_background(image, thresh, scale_factor=.25, kernel_range=range(1, 15), border=None):
        border = border or kernel_range[-1]

        holes = get_holes(image, thresh)
        small = cv2.resize(holes, None, fx=scale_factor, fy=scale_factor)
        bordered = cv2.copyMakeBorder(small, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

        for i in kernel_range:
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2*i+1, 2*i+1))
            bordered = cv2.morphologyEx(bordered, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        unbordered = bordered[border: -border, border: -border]
        mask = cv2.resize(unbordered, (image.shape[1], image.shape[0]))
        fg = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
        return fg

file = your_file_location
img = cv2.imread(file)
nb_img = dm.remove_background(img, 255)
```

These are some example images

[image: sample 1]

[image: sample 2]

May i have your suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple approach with the assumption that there is only one specimen per image.

1. **Kmeans color quantization.** We load the image then perform Kmeans color quantization to segment the image into a specified cluster of colors. For instance with `clusters=4`, the image will be labeled into four colors.
2. **Obtain binary image.** Convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, adaptive threshold.
3. **Draw largest enclosing circle onto mask.** Find contours, sort for largest contour using contour area filtering then draw the largest enclosing circle onto a mask using [`cv2.minEnclosingCircle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle).
4. **Bitwise-and.** Since we have isolated the desired sections to extract, we simply bitwise-and the mask and input image

---

Input image `->` Kmeans `->` Binary image

[image]
[image]
[image]

Detected largest enclosing circle `->` Mask `->` Result

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the output for the second image

Input image `->` Kmeans `->` Binary image

[image]
[image]
[image]

Detected largest enclosing circle `->` Mask `->` Result

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Kmeans color segmentation
def kmeans_color_quantization(image, clusters=8, rounds=1):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    samples = np.zeros([h*w,3], dtype=np.float32)
    count = 0

    for x in range(h):
        for y in range(w):
            samples[count] = image[x][y]
            count += 1

    compactness, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(samples,
            clusters, 
            None,
            (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10000, 0.0001), 
            rounds, 
            cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    centers = np.uint8(centers)
    res = centers[labels.flatten()]
    return res.reshape((image.shape))

# Load image and perform kmeans
image = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
original = image.copy()
kmeans = kmeans_color_quantization(image, clusters=4)

# Convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, adaptive threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(kmeans, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,2)

# Draw largest enclosing circle onto a mask
mask = np.zeros(original.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), 2)
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), 255, -1)
    break

# Bitwise-and for result
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('kmeans', kmeans)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: What if i have the specimen that is not in the circle shape but ellipse.  I think that i should modify the line cv2.minEncloseingCircle(c) to something else.  May i have your suggestions?

Comment: You can try [`cv2.fitEllipse`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_properties/py_contour_properties.html#orientation)

Comment: Another method you could try if its not a perfect circle but elliptical is instead of obtaining the mask using some circle/ellipse fit function, you can simply find contours with `cv2.findContours` then draw the largest contour with `cv2.drawContours` onto a mask. It should work with any orientation