# How to remove the area outside of the selected contour OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have some pictures like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0WDq.jpg)

After choosing the contour that I want by `index` by the function `cv2.findContours`: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F06JW.jpg)

I want to remove the nearly white background outside this contour. I tried this method: [Removing background color from image opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302695/removing-background-color-from-image-opencv-python) but I don't know how to modify the mask such that the inner area of the contour is white and the outer is back.

Could anyone tell me how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you have your mask, just invert as follows assuming it is 0 (black) and 255 (white): `mask = 255 - mask`

Comment: But I don't know how to create a mask such that the area inside contour is white and the outer is back.

Comment: How does your expected output may look like?

Comment: I expect the output just has the rock in a full-white background

Comment: You said you had a mask image already. Did I misunderstand? If not, use cv2.drawContours() on a black image and set the flag to -1 for the thickness and the color to white and it will be a filled contour with the center white on a black background. Then invert. Or draw a black filled contour on white background image. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc